# android studio json array response

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley, retrofit2

i have been trying to get a json response from an API by openweathermaps and i can't seem to make it work with either volley or retrofit, i will post the volley and retrofit functions and the errors i get on both and the json message itself

this is the json response that i am trying to capture
http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=10&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

this is the volley code "surprising enough i do get the response of the json that i am looking for, but i get it on the on volley error msg"

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            mJSONURLString,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    textView.setText(response.toString());
                    try{
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){

                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    // this is where i get my json "how?"
                    System.out.println(error);
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

and this is the retrofit code on a totally different project "i am testing both atm"

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    CitiesArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(CitiesArrayAPI.class);
    Call<List<Cities>> call = service.loadCitiesFromAPI();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Cities>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Cities>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            System.out.println("test");
            try {
                List<Cities> cities = response.body();
                for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

this is the retrofit interface for the arrayapi

```
public interface CitiesArrayAPI {
@GET("data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=5&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22")
Call<List<Cities>> loadCitiesFromAPI();
```

}

this is the error i get from the retrofit, works on the onFailure method

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Comment: It looks you are not casting that response in proper format as you are not only getting list in response so you cannot directly pass that data to list.

Comment: so how do i read both an object and an array at the same time?

Comment: if i understood u correctly then what u meant was that i am not getting the list[ ] alone so i should find a way to read the whole thing and then use the list[ ] alone, right?

Comment: Yup, you should use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for paasing response to java class

Comment: i have no idea what's that tbh

Comment: Simply put your response to that site and parse that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you expect a list where an object is returned
So change the retrofit interface to return object not list

```
public interface CitiesArrayAPI {
@GET("data/2.5/find?lat=55.5&lon=37.5&cnt=5&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22")
Call<Cities> loadCitiesFromAPI();
}
```

Add a class called Coord

```
public class Coord {

@Expose
@SerializedName("lat")
private double lat;

@Expose
@SerializedName("lng")
private double lng;

private double getLat(){
    return lat;
}
 private double getLng(){
    return lng;
}
}
```

And create object City which has a coord object

```
public class City {

@Expose
@SerializedName("coord")
private Coord coord;

private Coord getCoord(){
    return coord;
}
}
```

And class Cities which is a list and this object is the one called in the retrofit interface

```
public class Cities {

@SerializedName("cities")
private List<City> cities;
}
```

Then in the response you can call

```
response.body.getCoord().getlat();
```

Comment: this is pretty much the same as the other answer and they are both working perfectly but i have a minor problem still, for stuff like lat and lng they are inside an array named coord, how do i manage to get those ones

Comment: you are most welcome.please choose my answer as the correct one if it worked for you.@MahmoudOmara  P.S the answer you checked is not mine.Thanks

Comment: tbh both answers worked cause its the same thing :P but u did the follow up while he replied first xD im confused on who to verify as the answer, wish i could have made both

Answer (score 0):

The json you've trying to parse is certainly not `List<Cities>` thus the error which says "you are trying to parse array but you actually have an object"

here is how you root object should look like

```
public class YouRootObject {

    @SerializedName("message")
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("cod")
    private String cod;
    @SerializedName("count")
    private Integer count;
    @SerializedName("list")
    private List<City> cities;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(String cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<City> getList() {
        return cities;
    }

    public void setList(List<City> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
    }
}
```

and then instead of `<List<Cities>>` you should have `<YouRootObject>`

i.e. `Call<List<Cities>>` => `Call<YouRootObject>`and `Callback<List<Cities>>` => `Callback<YouRootObject>`

Comment: this makes absolute perfect sense, i will work on implementing it now, but one quick question, i don't want all the variables inside the list thing so in the city java class do i still have to declare all of them or just the ones i want?

Comment: ok this is working perfectly to get the variables like id and name inside the list [], but for stuff like lat and lng they are inside an array named coord, how do i manage to get those ones

Comment: @MahmoudOmara you can skip all properties you are not interested in. for nested entries like `coord` and `main` you have to create appropriate java objects. here is site that can do it automatically for you http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
just copy paste your json there, set properties on right panel and generate object. thank me later